Can I Submit My Accepted Abstract to Another Journal?
I recently had an abstract accepted for a special issue of a journal. However, after some consideration, I think another journal might be a better fit for my work. Before I proceed, I wanted to ask if anyone has experience with this or knows whether it is procedurally acceptable to withdraw the abstract and submit it elsewhere.
The abstract has only been accepted, and I have not submitted the full manuscript yet. Would withdrawing the abstract from the special issue and submitting it to another journal violate any norms or expectations?

I am assuming abstract submissions for this special issue have closed?

Standard and ethical practice is to submit to one journal at a time. If you wish to submit elsewhere, withdraw the submission first. A note to the editor is all you need to do unless you have already signed over your copyrights, in which case they need to agree.
Multiple submissions wastes resources, namely the time and effort of those involved, especially reviewers. Moreover, in a case like this, leaving the editors thinking that you are still committed, means that "space" is being saved for you that might go to another.  If lots of people do this it negatively affects everyone.
Don't get a "norm-breaking" reputation with editors and the people who donate time and effort to make the system work.
